# How do I prevent network issues from duplicate VMs in VMware vSphere?

Tags: linux, networking, vmware, esxi

I have a nested ESXi cluster for my VMware vSphere lab (just a single MacPro 1.1 host running ESXi 6.0). I have four VM templates that I deploy for testing, learning and labbing purposes (I do not have a lot of resources, before anyone judges my choices here):
 - CentOS 7 minimal (x86)
 - Tiny Core Linux 10
 - Windows XP (again, extremely limited resources in my lab)
 - Windows 2000 (actually works better than XP for my purposes)

For the Windows VMs I can SysPrep them to avoid issues that arise from duplicates....but what is the equivalent for the Linux VMs? I realize TC Linux is a bit niche, so a CentOS solution would be adequate. The problem I seem to face is that **when a duplicate VM exists on the network it cannot get an IP** from DHCP and even if I statically assign one, networking functionality is broken for whatever reason. So, my questions are:

1. (Mostly for my own edification) What might be causing this issue?
2. What can I do to ensure the duplicate VMs function properly on the network?

Please note: I am already using **automatic MAC address randomization** so that should not be the issue.

Comment: Have you confirmed the MAC address is actually different in the OS?

Comment: Yes, I just spun up 2x TC Linux VMs and the MACs are unique....I'm actually not having the problem at the moment (they both received a good IP via DHCP) and both of these TCL VMs have the same hostname (simply "box"), so perhaps this is related to my VLANs or another network issue. :/

Comment: Any duplication concerns are addressed by the fact you are using a template to deploy additional machines.  You only have to worry about the name of the machine.